# Why does template create a local copy of second parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Was going through templates. Way to pass two template parameters are:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline T1 max (T1 const& a, T2 const& b) {
  return a < b ? b : a;
}
…
max(4,4.2) // OK, but type of first argument defines return type
```

Two drawbacks to this:

1. Argument for the other parameter(T2) might get converted to this type, regardless of the caller's intention.
2. Converting the type of the second parameter into the return type creates a new, local temporary object.

I understand first one but not the second one. What really happens in context to second point?

Comment: Perhaps you should use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) for the return-type? Still doesn't negates the need for a conversion if `T1` and `T2` are different though.

Answer (score 3):

If `a < b` is true, then `b` is returned.  However, that needs to be converted from `T2` to `T1`.  That requires a copy (which may be optimised away in simple cases).

Comment: Ohh Ok. Automatic type conversion does not happen inside templates. Is that the reason they create copies for different types?

Comment: If `a < b` is false, then `a` is returned

Answer (score 1):

It makes a copy because you return by value. Template types are just like normal types in the end, after all.

If you'd like to return a const ref, return `const T1&`, although that will constrain `T2` to actually be `T1`.

We can do more complicated templating to cover both scenarios and return by value when the types differ, but return by const ref if they don't, but that is perhaps out of the scope of your exercise